# Only last connected client receives message

Tags: java, client, server, lan

I have a Server-Client program where I want to communicate with all the connected clients using a `JLabel(MouseClick)`. But the message is only getting delivered to the last Client connected. I not able to identify the problem. Here is my code

//server

```
void connect_clients()
    {
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
            jButton1.setText("Server Running!");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                while (true) {

                    socket = listener.accept();
                    try {
                            clientIP = socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName();
                        }    
                    catch(Exception e){}
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}

            }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
        }
    }
}                                    

private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    PrintWriter out;
     try {
         out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
         out.println("pc2");
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(third_frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

//Client

```
void connect_server()
    {
        try {
           while(true)
        {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
                            "running the date service on port 9090:");
            s = new Socket(serverAddress, 7700);


            BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String answer = input.readLine();

            System.out.println(answer);
            answer = null;
          }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(client_form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: `Socket` is declared globally in both Server and Client.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the server accepts a connetion, it creates a new socket representing it. Since you are overriding the socket reference each time a new connection is estabilished, you are only holding a reference to the last connection.

```
private List<Socket> socketList;
...

ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
socketList = new ArrayList<>();
...

socketList.add(listener.accept());
...

for (Socket socket: socketList) {
   out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
   out.println("pc2");
   ...
}
```

Comment: So how can i store each the reference of each client and use them later when I want? @Renatols

Comment: You could create a List and add the socket created by the server to it so you could traverse it to send the messages.

Comment: Can you give me example for implementing this?  @Renatols

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you a brief idea of how you could do it.

Comment: When I implement this method my messages are getting delivered only to 1st client. @Renatols